# connect visual studio 2010 to Solid Works

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008, solidworks

I have created form in visual sutio 2010 and added button in that 
when user clicks the button it should open Solid Works tool so code is :

```
Imports SolidWorks.Interop.sldworks
Imports SolidWorks.Interop.swconst
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports System
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)        Handles Button1.Click
    Dim swDoc As ModelDoc2 = Nothing
    Dim swPart As PartDoc = Nothing
    Dim swDrawing As DrawingDoc = Nothing
    Dim swAssembly As AssemblyDoc = Nothing
    Dim boolstatus As Boolean = False
    swDoc = CType(swApp.NewDocument("C:\ProgramData\SolidWorks\SolidWorks 2012\templates\Part.prtdot", 0, 0, 0), ModelDoc2)
    swDoc = CType(swApp.ActiveDoc, ModelDoc2)
    boolstatus = swDoc.Extension.SelectByID2("Top Plane", "PLANE", 0, 0, 0, False, 0, Nothing, 0)
    swDoc.SketchManager.InsertSketch(True)
    Dim skSegment As SketchSegment = Nothing
    skSegment = CType(swDoc.SketchManager.CreateCircle(-0.020947, 0.005368, 0, 0.012306, -0.016627, 0), SketchSegment)
    boolstatus = swDoc.EditRebuild3()
End Sub
End Class
```

but unfortunately i am getting error in importing please help me
error are :

> imports does not contain any public member or cannot be found

Comment: Remove CAPS please, and precise which error you get

Comment: @SteveB please check the edited qstn

Comment: please change the question title to something meaningful, and include Solid Works

Comment: @jcfx please help me to connect my visual basic GUI to solid works please

Comment: @M_S_SAJJAN I really don't know how to, sorry.

Comment: @SteveB please help me to connect my visual basic GUI to solid works please

Comment: @M_S_SAJJAN: I would have answered if I was able.

Answer (score 2):

Add these dlls as references to your project:
SolidWorks.Interop.sldworks.dll 
SolidWorks.Interop.swconst.dll

These dlls located in Solidworks folder. On my PC it's 

C:\Program Files\SolidWorks Corp\SolidWorks\

Answer (score 2):

If you want to start SolidWorks from an application (click on a button and launch SoWo),
then you should:

1) Add the necessary references to the SolidWorks Interop libraries (as Vladyslav Litunovsky has correctly pointed out)

2) "Attach/Connect" to the SolidWorks Application (Object) in order to get your application to start and work with SolidWorks.

If you need exact control on which SolidWorks session you want to attach (i.e. if more then 1 is running), then things are getting a bit more work intensive, as you have to work using the ROT (RunningObjectTable), where you could grab a potentially running SolidWorks instance.

In general, you could use

```
Set swApp = CreateObject("SldWorks.Application")
```

or a version dependent instancing (in this case 21 = 2013) if you have more than a version on the target system and would like to exactly run a specific version:

```
Set swApp = CreateObject("SldWorks.Application.21") //
```

This attaches to an existing SolidWorks session or creates a new one.

Please be aware that programmaticaly starting and ending a SolidWorks session, does involve additional parameters / properties that control how the session should be terminated and/or displayed.

You might look into this for more details (shows how to instanciate and control a SolidWorks session):

http://help.solidworks.com/2013/English/api/sldworksapi/solidworks_visible_or_background_example_vb.htm